# How to link interactive problems (w.r.t. CodeJam)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interactive

I'm not sure if it's allowed to seek for help(if not, I don't mind not getting an answer until the competition period is over).

I was solving the Interactive Problem ([Dat Bae](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/round/0000000000051705/00000000000881de)) on CodeJam. On my local files, I can run the judge (`testing_tool.py`) and my program (`<name>.py`) separately and copy paste the I/O manually. However, I assume I need to find a way to make it automatically.

Edit: To make it clear, I want every output of x file to be input in y file and vice versa.

Some details:

1. I've used `sys.stdout.write` / `sys.stdin.readline` instead of print / input throughout my program
2. I tried running `interactive_runner.py`, but I don't seem to figure out how to use it.
3. I tried running it on their server, my program in first tab, the judge file in second. It's always throwing TLE error.

I don't seem to find any tutorial to do the same either, any help will be appreciated! :/

Answer (score 6):

The usage is documented in comments inside the scripts:

**interactive_runner.py**

```
# Run this as:
# python interactive_runner.py <cmd_line_judge> -- <cmd_line_solution>
#
# For example:
# python interactive_runner.py python judge.py 0 -- ./my_binary
#
# This will run the first test set of a python judge called "judge.py" that
# receives the test set number (starting from 0) via command line parameter
# with a solution compiled into a binary called "my_binary".
```

**testing_tool.py**

```
# Usage: `testing_tool.py test_number`, where the argument test_number
# is 0 for Test Set 1 or 1 for Test Set 2.
```

So use them like this:

```
python interactive_runner.py python testing_tool.py 0 -- ./dat_bae.py
```

Comment: Hey, 
     Not sure how I missed the '0' initially. However, on running, I'm getting another error: 'OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application'. I installed 32-bit, created venv for 32-bit, but still no the same error pops up :/

Comment: FWIW, in the [FAQ](https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/codejam/faq) it's recommended that you replicate the google platform's environment for testing, that is use Linux and Python 3.5.3.